# Downloading only the first n number of children nodes (Firebase, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I’m trying to create an application similar to Twitter however my understaning is that if I add all “tweets” as children to a “post” node, when I try and retrieve these children I will have to download all of the posts. As the app scales this will result in downloading millions of posts. Is there a way I can retrieve only the first say 25 posts?

Comment: Post your code with relevant data

Comment: Right now it's not clear what part of Firebase you're using. But if you are using the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) then you can [use a query to limit to the first 25 posts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: You’re right, I was using the Firebase real time database. And thank you this should resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently returned to this issue and found a solution. Rather than implementing a simple read request, it is possible to create a firebase query.

First, a child should be added to the "post" node to store the reversed time stamp of the post.

```
let timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970 //timestamp
let reversedTimestamp = -1.0 * timestamp //reverse time stamp
```

Now, it is possible to create a query by adding .queryOrdered(byChild: "reverseTimestamp").queryLimited(toFirst:25). This returns the 25 most recent posts under a child in the database.

```
ref.child("walls").child(userCredentials.getResidenceCode()).queryOrdered(byChild: "reverseTimestamp").queryLimited(toFirst: 25).observe(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```